# Graded readers for Thai language?

Tags: graded-readers, thai

We have links to graded readers for many languages, like [Japanese](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/3184/graded-readers-for-japanese), [Russian](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/3269/where-can-i-find-graded-readers-for-russian) etc, because it is commonly considered an excellent way to improve language skills.

Does community has any suggestions for graded readers for Thai language?

There was a Thai Language proposal in Area 51 a year ago or so, but seems to disappeared since.

Answer (score 3):

I found these [short articles](http://www.thai-language.com/lessons) on (IMHO very good, or at least the best free website I could find) http://www.thai-language.com/ website. They have text in Thai, transcription to tones, and translation.